# How to create an embeddedlist with Class type?

Tags: orientdb

I'm using OrientDB 3.0.1

I created an embeddelist property using:

```
CREATE PROPERTY MyClass.property1 EMBEDDEDLIST
```

And everything works fine (reading, writing) using sql.

But, I want an embeddedlist of only documents of certain type, what I want is to do something like this:

```
CREATE PROPERTY MyClass.property2 EMBEDDEDLIST AnotherClass
```

And then I want to do this:

```
insert into MyClass content { "property2": [{ "@Class":"AnotherClass"...},{"@Class":"AnotherClass"...}]}
```

I get this error:

The field 'MyClass.property2' has been declared as EMBEDDEDLIST but an incompatible type is used

So, how can I force/validate that my embeddedList only accepts documents of a specific Class? Maybe using a Hook?

**Update: it works now in Orient 3.0.2 (Thanks Luigi!)** here is the solution:

```
create class OneClass extends V;
create property OneClass.myList embeddedlist Coordinates;

insert into OneClass set myList = [
                {
                    "@class": "Coordinates",
                    "latitude": 6511,
                    "longitude": 3
                },
                {
                    "@class": "Coordinates",
                    "latitude": 6518,
                    "longitude": 3
                }
];
```

Comment: Hi, could you open an issue on github.com ? Thx

Comment: Issue added in github. And now it is solved. I am putting the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in v 3.0.1 and is already fixed in v 3.0.2.

Comment: Thanks Luigi! I confirm it works in Orient 3.0.2   I will add the solution to the question